# Is this meaning of "smallest" and "largest'" topologies wrong?

Tags: general-topology

One of Munkres' exercises has me prove "(...) there is a unique smallest topology, which contains all (...)", and "(...) a unique largest topology, contained in all (...)". The problem I'm having with the exercise is not proving that, I'm asking why the author uses "smallest" for "contains all topologies" and "largest" for "contained in all topologies". Should it not be the exact opposite? This definition would lead me to believe the indiscrete topology is "bigger" than the 
discrete topology, which is obviously false. What's going on here?

[image: I filled in the (...)]

Comment: What is the smallest integer $n$ such that $n \ge \frac{m}{m+1}$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: In your quote, you have inserted a comma that wasn't in the original. This changes everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're misparsing the phrase. E.g.

> "There is a unique smallest topology, which contains all ..."

does not mean "The unique smallest topology contains all ..." but rather "There is a unique (smallest topology which contains all ...)."

It's like saying "There is a unique smallest integer, which is bigger than $7$" - namely, $8$.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks.

Comment: The comma (which is not in the original) is the problematic element here. To say "There is a unique smallest integer which is bigger than $7$" is fine (it is $8$), but to use a comma is wrong. "There is a unique smallest integer, which is bigger than $7$" is a false statement.

Comment: I see my mistake now. Guess I'm just too used to putting commas everywhere I can.

Comment: @Théophile Yes, and note that it seems that that comma does not appear in the original text.

Comment: Indeed, the comma was not in the original, and the placing of it in my quote did change everything. I appreciate you guys pointing it out. It's painfully obvious now how I screwed up... just needed someone else's perspective on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are mis-parsing these phrases.  "Smallest topology containing all the $\mathcal{T}_\alpha$" should be read as "smallest (topology which contains all the $\mathcal{T}_\alpha$)".  That is, it is a topology $T$ which contains each $\mathcal{T}_\alpha$, such that if $T'$ is any other topology that contains each $\mathcal{T}_\alpha$, then $T\subseteq T'$.